# running sun java from cygwin

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cygwin

I have installed cygwin in C:\deepan\cygwin\ directory... how do I reinstall it in C:\ directory?  I want to be able to run java in C:\programfiles\java\ folder from cygwin

Comment: Shouldn't that kind of question be asked on SuperUser ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following command (with-in Cygwin):

*cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/"*

regardless of where you have cygwin installed you can change directories internally.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run Java from anywhere you don't need to reinstall cygwin. You should be able to do this  
 - add the java path to the paths (best solution): `export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102"` 
`export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`  
 - create aliases like: `alias java="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java.exe"` 
 - create symbolic link: `ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java.exe /usr/bin/java`